# How to add visited attribute to html a label?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, onclick, visited

I am trying to add visited attribute to html a label, just like below case:

```css
a:visited {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="play(0,0);">Some Text</a>
```

but it's not working.

Could you please help to point out why it's not working?

Thank you!

Comment: But `javascript:;` is not a link. [:visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) applies if it is link. Replace href value with some id and recheck.

Comment: Yes, it's the root cause. Thanks.